# how to normalize curvature to be between -1 and -1/4

Tags: non-positive-curvature

On paper "Harmonic maps into singular spaces and p-adic superrigidity for lattices in groups of rank one", lemma 8.1, when the author tried to construct finite energy map from Quaternion hyperbolic space or Cayley plane, they normalize the curvature to be between -1 and -1/4. My question is under what condition can we do this and how to realize this? Any reference will be much appreciated.

Comment: There is more than one standard convention for the usual metrics on the quaternion hyperbolic plane, and on the Cayley hyperbolic plane, but differentt conventions agree up to positive constant rescaling. In any such rescaling, the ratio of maximum to minimum of absolute sectional curvature is 4, so we can pick the constant rescaling to get the required curvature range. See Besse, Einstein Manifolds, I think, for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, Ben.